# Replica using DTU pricing model

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-replication

I have a Azure SQL Db configure with DTU-based pricing model. I'm trying to create a Replica in a secondary region for the DB. But when I try to configure it using the Azure portal, there is no option to select the service tier as DTU. Is this a limitation or am I missing some configuration?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I checked the same configuration page for some of my test databases, and it gives me the DTU option if the database is also on DTU model and vCore option if the database is on vCore model. So I can't replicate this issue for some reason :\

Comment: Is the Region UKWest could be causing the problem.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screen you shared with us it seems to me you are not following the steps outlined on [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-configure-portal?view=azuresql&tabs=portal).

If I follow the steps provided on the documentation, I initiate the creation of the replica by selecting the options shown on below screenshot:

[image]

When I do that Azure Portal shows me a different web page to continue the process of creating the replica than the one you shared with us.

[image]

If I scroll down that page, I am able to see the service tier. Basic tier (DTU model) in my case.

[image]

Comment: I have followed exactly the steps in the documentation. I dont see the option for DTU. Its like in the screenshot I shared in the question. Unless, its not available in the UK West.

Comment: Azure will create the replica with the same service tier anyways. Some people lower the service tier of the replica to save money, but that is not recommended. Go ahead and proceed.

Comment: I found the issue, initial db that was created via portal had DTU. But later a new DB was restored from backup and it defaulted to vCore model after restore(not sure why it didnt ask to choose the model). So the reason the options for DTU were disabled.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. It is the first time I read about that scenario.